# Sorting a queryset in for loop in a Django template not working

Tags: django, sorting, for-loop, templates

I'm having a problem with django's for loop template tag not sorted.

```
{% for profile in profiles|sort_list:filter_args %}
  my code here
{% endfor %}
```

'profiles' is a list of dictionaries, and I'm trying to sort the list based on a chosen sort option from input on the page.

```
<select name="sort" id="sort" onchange="sort();">
  <option value="username">username</option>
  <option value="age">age</option>
  <option value="height">height</option>
</select>
```

The logic I used follows the steps.

1. Manually change the sorting option like sort by username or sort by age, etc..
2. Javascript detects the onchange event and send a request to the server using Ajax.
3. The server returns the sort and reverse options like

```
filter_args = {'sort_by': 'username', 'up_down': 'up'}
```

4. 'filter_args' goes into a custom template tag filter defined as

```
def sort_list(profiles, filter_args):
    sort_by = filter_args["sort_by"]
    up_down = filter_args["up_down"]
    if up_down == "down":
        profiles = sorted(profiles, key=lambda i: i[sort_by], reverse=True)
    else:
        profiles = sorted(profiles, key=lambda i: i[sort_by])
    return profiles
```

5. Then, I should see that the profiles list is sorted. And HTML elements in the for loop should sorted too.

```
{% for profile in profiles|sort_list:filter_args %}
  my code here
{% endfor %}
```

I also made sure that the custom template tag works fine (put print() in the function).

```
def sort_list(profiles, filter_args):
    sort_by = filter_args["sort_by"]
    up_down = filter_args["up_down"]
    if up_down == "down":
        profiles = sorted(profiles, key=lambda i: i[sort_by], reverse=True)
    else:
        profiles = sorted(profiles, key=lambda i: i[sort_by])

    for x in profiles:
        print(x["username"])
    return profiles
```

After running, I could see that queryset is sorted as I want.
But it seems like it doesn't make any effect on for loop.

I don't see any change before and after I put the logic.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Sort your query in the view and return as context

Comment: I already did. I made 'my code here' part in the views and used {{ something | safe }}. But there was no change.

Comment: Ajax uses POST request but the server returns using render() just like normal access.  I feel something wrong with this.

Comment: @AsherNagasaki Your html once rendered (and sent to the client) has nothing to do with the server. You are expecting that just changing filter_args on a request by ajax would change your html. You need to return some html in the response to the ajax request and use javascript to put it in the correct place.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you so much! I used HttpResponse and made Ajax put the response code to the correct place. Now it's working!